# LeftMouse click event on android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

How to do this on Android? is this possible? I want to make a click event on where the mouse is pointing programmatically. Actually the mouse arrow is pointed on a button. I tried

```
button.performClick();
button.setPressed(true);
```

but it did not activate my `button.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener() );`

So maybe a mouse click event will do...

Comment: Are you aiming to develop an application using on Emulator only?A real android device doesn't have a mouse!?!

Comment: Like a touch or something related to a leftclick of a mouse....

Comment: As far as I know,it's impossible to do such an event, on onTouch event require a physical  impact on your screen (the sensor on your screen make that event and pass down to your application). You can't simulate that.

Comment: What you mean is that you can't make the button already activated by the draglistener while not touching it?